# Go SQL connector won't give me result of special select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm trying to get from database information about all tables and their columns. Unfortunately i always get null.

This is my function to get tables with columns from database.

```
func GetTablesAndColumns(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    columns := repository.GetAllTablesWithColumns()

    err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(columns)
    errorHandler.CheckError(err)
}
```

```
func GetAllTablesWithColumns() []entity.TablesColumns {
    var tablesColumns []entity.TablesColumns
    results, err := server.Select("SELECT tb.table_name as TableName, c.column_name as ColumnName, c.data_type as DataType FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tb left join information_schema.columns c on tb.table_name = c.table_name WHERE tb.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' and tb.table_schema = 'public';")
    for results.Next() {
        var tableColumn entity.TablesColumns

        err = ScanTablesData(results, &tableColumn)
        errorHandler.CheckError(err)

        tablesColumns = append(tablesColumns, tableColumn)
    }

    return tablesColumns
}
```

```
func Select(query string) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    connector = singleton.OpenConnection("postgresql")
    query = strings.ToLower(query)
    if !strings.Contains(query, "select") {
        panic("Can't use select query to run different query")
    }

    results, err := connector.Query(query)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    return results, err
}
```

```
type TablesColumns struct {
    TableName string `json:"tableName"`
    ColumnName string `json:"columnName"`
    DataType string `json:"dataType"`
}
```

i did with with this little trick:

```
CREATE VIEW db_tables_with_columns AS
SELECT tb.table_name as TableName, c.column_name as ColumnName, c.data_type as DataType
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tb
         left join information_schema.columns c on tb.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE tb.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  and tb.table_schema = 'public';
```

i made a view in database and now everything is working good.
i got json object with data hmm. how can i explain this? what happend?

Comment: When you say "I always get null" do you mean that `server.Select` returns no results or are you getting results but `ScanTablesData()` is not populating the fields in `TablesColumns` (if that is the case you will need to show us `ScanTablesData`).

Comment: i'm pretty sure server.Select is null  cause i fmt.Println this - results.Next() 
and its null

Comment: i made another test with normal query, something like ->  results, err := server.Select("select * from cities") now fmt.Println(results.Next()) returns TRUE and everything is working fine

Comment: i did it with VIEW trick. Can you look at this? i wrote about this in main post, thank you fro your resposne

Comment: Possible that the user you are connecting as does not have access to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Try connecting  using `psql` (with the user/password used by your application) and run the same query.